# Many to many field for multiple user type in Django

Tags: python, django, authentication, model, many-to-many

I am trying to create multiple User types where a single user can be of multiple types. This is the model class I am using:

```
class Role(models.Model):
  '''
  The Role entries are managed by the system,
  automatically created via a Django data migration.
  '''
  STUDENT = 1
  TEACHER = 2
  SECRETARY = 3
  SUPERVISOR = 4
  ADMIN = 5
  ROLE_CHOICES = (
      (STUDENT, 'student'),
      (TEACHER, 'teacher'),
      (SECRETARY, 'secretary'),
      (SUPERVISOR, 'supervisor'),
      (ADMIN, 'admin'),
  )

  id = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(choices=ROLE_CHOICES, primary_key=True)

  def __str__(self):
      return self.get_id_display()


class User(AbstractUser):
  roles = models.ManyToManyField(Role)
```

When I create user from the django admin panel, the roles field should allow me to select multiple user types but instead, it shows me a blank box.[Image of the admin panel.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cf1LK.png)

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, you only want 5 roles.  Go into admin for Roles and create one of each type. You should see the user_role field list populated after that

The way you think it would work would only be if Role was a choice-type field of User.  As Role is its own model, you need to create the types you want to use in the field. Imagine if you were choosing other users you wanted to follow in a many-to-many relationship.  You'd need other actual user records to choose from - the same principle applies here.

Comment: ...or write a migration to do the same for reproducibility and easier management instead of creating via admin.

Comment: Thanks! The first method worked. But what is the better way of doing this in my scenario. Using a choice field or a many-to-many relationship? And I think there is no multiple choice field in django model. But there is in django forms.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with your approach, especially with many-to-many relationships. SUTerliakov above correctly notes that you might want to write some code that will set up the records you want to use in new environments the same way each time.  That could be a migration, or a django management command: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/howto/custom-management-commands/. If you are only using Roles for for permissions, you could also look into groups: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/auth/default/#groups